# Can I make the default input color picker type to checker grid/transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am using `ngx-color` plugin of `Angular`. So my goal is to make the color picker look like this the below picker (checker grid) if no color is selected. Means by default this is what I want to show to user. Is it possible?

[image]

My code

```html
<input class="color-input" [(colorPicker)]="selectedColor"
       [style.background]="selectedColor" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeColor()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ngClass](https://www.developer.com/java/data/applying-conditional-styles-to-components-using-angular-declarations/) to use conditional class to your component.
When you have no selectedColor, you set a class that will have the configurations you need to achieve that look like your example.

Example:
Html:

```
<input class="color-input" [ngClass]="{ 'no-color': selectedColor == null }" [(colorPicker)]="selectedColor"
       [style.background]="selectedColor" (cpSliderDragEnd)="changeColor()">
```

CSS:

```css
.no-color {
   background: white;
   background-image: 'path-to-image';
.
.
.
}
```